# How can code be built for a diagram with array elements looped?

Tags: python, arrays, reference

[image]

In the image below, I came up with something like this but I know this produces an error. I am writing in python

```
    def return_this(arr,x,y):
        arr = [10, [30, [x,y], 40]]
        return arr[1][0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your solution, you need to create 4 array with values and for empty one put None at start.

Now once declare you need to reference the array to other array. and it is done
you can check them out but indexing the internal indexes where they point out

```
>>> 
>>> a =[None, None]
>>> b =[10, None]
>>> c = [None, 20]
>>> d = [30, None, 40]
>>> 
>>> a[0] = b
>>> a[1] =c
>>> b[1] = d
>>> c[0] =d
>>> d[1] = a
>>> 
>>> a
[[10, [30, [...], 40]], [[30, [...], 40], 20]]
>>> b
[10, [30, [[...], [[...], 20]], 40]]
>>> c
[[30, [[10, [...]], [...]], 40], 20]
>>> d
[30, [[10, [...]], [[...], 20]], 40]
```

note: you need to return `a[0]` in your function